# How to make a ListField of ReferenceFields unique?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm trying to make a `ListField` of `ReferenceField` unique, but I'm getting a unique error when I shouldn't. Why is that?

```
class Training(Document):

    transactions = ListField(ReferenceField(Buy, reverse_delete_rule=PULL), default=list, unique=True)

b = Buy()
b.save()
b1 = Buy()
b1.save()
b2 = Buy()
b2.save()

# both should save fine since the lists are different
Training(transactions=[b, b1]).save()

Training(transactions=[b, b2]).save()
```

NotUniqueError: Tried to save duplicate unique keys (E11000 duplicate key error collection: test_db.training index: transactions_1 dup key: { : ObjectId('575d33eceefe54280475fc1b') })